# Evaluate determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix, help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I need help with this problem:

$D_{n}= \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1& 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0& 1 & 1
        \end{vmatrix}$

I can't get it to squared form. It is obvious that fourth row is needed. How to find fourth row, or is there other methods?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Do you not see the pattern?  You have $1$'s on the main diagonal and the diagonals immediately above and below that, everything else $0$.  The fourth row is $[0,0,1,1,1,0,\ldots,0]$.

Comment: I am not sure that you understand the meaning of the dots.

Comment: Hint: cofactor expand along the top row. After this, and another cofactor expansion of one of the smaller resulting matrices, you should get an expression for $D_n$ in terms of $D_{n-1}$ and $D_{n-2}$. You will then need to solve this recurrence relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a special case of a tridiagonal matrix. If you denote this determinant $D_n$, developing it along the last row, you can prove the recurrence relation:
$$D_n=D_{n-1}-D_{n-2}$$
The initialisation is $D_1=1$, $D_2=0$. You can easily establish that

$$\begin{cases}
D_n=1&\text{if}\enspace n\equiv 0,1 \pmod6\\
D_n=0&\text{if}\enspace n\equiv 2,5 \\
D_n=-1&\text{if}\enspace n\equiv 3,4 
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&1\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
would be an example for your problem, using gaussian elimination it is easy to get it to the unit matrix, which has 1 as determinant.

Comment: How did you get 4 by 4 format of a matrix?

Comment: the dots indicate that the pattern is to be continued. The three 1 are always shifted to the right once more.

Comment: This is the case $n=4$.  The case $n=5$ would be $$\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\cr}$$